# How to change the font color in the title of iTerm 2?

Tags: macos, terminal, colors, zsh, iterm2

[image: The screenshot of what I'm trying to change]

Does anyone know what option should I put in `.zshrc` to change the font color in the title of `iTerm` from grey to white? I spent 24h and still couldn't find the right option because there are a lot of parameters. I'm on disability and it's very hard for me to go through every option. It's like searching for a needle in a haystack. The overall task is super simple, but I was unable to find the option in the `GUI`, and I was unable to find the actual command to change it via `.zshrc`. It drives me crazy... I now suspect that there must be another way of changing this. I found out that I can export my profile in `.json`. Probably in that file there should be an option to change the font color of the title. Let me know if you aware how to do that because I haven't tried the latest idea yet.

Comment: I doubt you can. That's a system window, not in the application's 'domain'.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you. I think it's possible. I will search for the solution and then will get back to post the answer. :)

Comment: Try the apps [GeekTool](https://www.tynsoe.org/geektool/) and [CrystalClear](http://www.marsthemes.com/crystalclear/).

Comment: @harrymc CrystalClear looks outdated, but GeekTool might help. Thank you. I would be able to test it tomorrow.

Comment: I was unable to find the solution... I was trying to modify the .json file of my profile, but it didn't change anything. Plus I'm not familiar with .json. I still think it's possible. Can someone please help? :) I clearly need some guidance to make those final changes. The tools mentioned above aren't suited for the task either.